# Equivalent of time(7) SQL Server 2008 datatype in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the equivalent of SQL Server 2008's `time(7)` datatype in .NET? I want to store hours and minutes alone in that column, for this which datatype should I use in SQL Server!

Comment: Can I use timespan datatype in dot net as equivalent for time(7) datatype in SQL server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a nice article from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150018/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101508-1.aspx) link.

I will use timespan datatype in dot net as equivalent for time(7) datatype in SQL server to store hours and minutes.

Answer (score 6):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) gives a mapping between SQL data types and CLR data types - and it suggests `TimeSpan` and `Nullable<TimeSpan>` (for nullable columns) too. Note that how you access the data will determine how you actually get the value out though. [`DbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.aspx) doesn't have a `GetTimeSpan` method for example - but `SqlDataReader` *does* have [such a method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.gettimespan.aspx). I'd expect LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework to perform the mapping automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet said, [Class SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does have a [GetTimeSpan Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.gettimespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

```
conn = new SqlConnection(blablabla);
conn.Open();

string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
    {
    MyVeryOwnModel mvom = new MyVeryOwnModel();
    mvom.timeStart = reader.GetTimeSpan(reader.GetOrdinal("column_time_start"));
    mvom.timeEnd = reader.GetTimeSpan(reader.GetOrdinal("column_time_end"));
    }

reader.Close();
```